# Using SC.get() inside a loop (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, soundcloud

Im storing track IDs in a database that are used as playlists.

The track ID data is retrieved using jQuery $.get() and is returned in a JSON array.

Next a jQuery $.each() loops a SC.get('/tracks/') that is passed the relevant track id.

```
$.each(pl_array.track, function(i) {
    var pl_track_id = '/tracks/' + pl_array.track[i].id;
    SC.get(pl_track_id,function (tracks) {
        //looped code here
    });
});
```

The problem is the SC.get() call is asynchronous, and will result in the tracks being ordered randomly. The jQuery $.get() has the option to disable asynchronous and run synchronously. Is there any way i can do somthing like this with the SC.get() function or is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.
SJAX freezes the browser and is extremely annoying.

If you really want synchronous processing, use recursion instead of a loop:

```
var items = ...;
function processItem() {
    var item = items.unshift();
    SC.get(item.id. function() { 
        ...
        if (items.length)
            processItem();
    });
}
```

However, it would be much faster to send all the requests at once (the way you're doing now), then sort the results after they all come in.

Comment: However its not a problem at all, its not that slow really. So I think this is problem solved, thank you very much :)